# MySQL not respond when overheaded

Tags: mysql

I have few Drupal 6 websites on webhosting, which causes this strange problem:

- some tables, especially Cache and Watchdog, tend to overhead,
- when overhead is bigger than some amount of kB, MySQL server is refusing connection to given Drupal database or connection is broken during query execution,
- Optimizing table (just overheaded rows) in phpMyAdmin is putting all back to normal.

But - until database is optimized, site is showing just MySQL errors, which is ugly... Where is a problem?

Thank you for any hints I could pass back to the hosting admins!

Comment: What MySQL errors are you seeing?

Comment: Unfortunately usually "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading." and/or "The connection to MySQL lost during the page loading." *****> E.g. now there were overheads in tables {cache} 52.1kB, {captcha_sessions} 9.4kB, {sessions} 10kB and {variable} 64B.
Given error message: "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading." =====> optimizing table {variables} did the trick (well, I've been optimizing in sequence {cache}, {sessions}, {variable}) to have website back and live.